# jQuery - Set each html() class value to another element

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:-

**HTML**

```
<div id="nottingham-park-wrapper">
  <div id="notts-main-court" class="icon-wrapper">
    <span class="park-marker"></span>
  </div>
  <span id="notts-main-court-info" class="notts-info">
  <h2 class="infobox-title">TITLE 1</h2>
  <p class="infobox-desc">TEXT INFO 1</p>
  </span>
  <div id="notts-dodgeball" class="icon-wrapper">
    <span class="park-marker"></span>
  </div>
  <span id="notts-dodgeball-info" class="notts-info">
  <h2 class="infobox-title">TITLE 2</h2>
  <p class="infobox-desc">TEXT INFO 2</p>
  </span>
</div>

<hr>

<span class="mobile-notts-info"></span>
```

**jQuery**

```
    jQuery(".notts-info").each(function(index) {
      var notts_info = jQuery(this).html();
      jQuery(this).html('');
      jQuery(".mobile-notts-info").html(notts_info);
    });
```

[VIEW JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/34dk6wq8/)

Basically I want to move each `.notts-info` html inside `.mobile-notts-info`

At the moment it is only moving the last value in the each loop, how can I get all values? (there is only 2 in this example, there are a lot more in the actual version which is why I want to use each instead of doing each element seperately)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want only html or whole `<span class="notts-info">`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.html()` removes existing contents and add new. due to which only last content are available in target parent. You need to use `.append()` instead of `.html()` to preserve existing and append new content as last child of parent:

```
jQuery(".mobile-notts-info").append(notts_info);
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L0qj8rx6/)**

However you don't need to iterate over elements, You can reduce your code to:

```
jQuery(".mobile-notts-info").append(jQuery(".notts-info"));
```

**[Optimised Code working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nygkn5fr/)**

Comment: @nsilva: glad it helps :)